# softlayer api: How to get the status(finish or processing) when copy os image cross IDC?

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I call `SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group:addLocations` to copy private image_A cross `IDC`, this function returns `True` immediately. So it is known that the operation is asynchronous.

The question is how can I know that this async operation is finished, namely `image_A` is already finished copy to the target `IDC`?

I have found the api:

`SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group:getTransaction()`, but this one always returns an empty str??What the hell ~ ~ ~

Comment: Same operation to image_A, in this time, I call removeLocations() to remove idc_x (the already existing idc),  the result is an exception:                 Traceback (most recent call last):
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group_ActiveTransactionExists): There is currently an outstanding transaction for this image template.                                                     But,SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group:getTransaction(), always return a empty str.

Comment: How can I get the currently an outstanding transaction status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the following call

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/$templateGroupId/getChildren?objectMask=mask[transaction]

Method: Get
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and **$templateGroupId**

You need to verify that the children (image template groups that are clones of an image template group) have no any pending or current transaction. In case that there is one or more transactions, you will not able to add/remove locations until this finishes.

Comment: Thanks. Prefect answer. Other relevant question: when I trigger the image copy cross idc, the children must in pending or current transaction. During this time,  I found that i can't create vm with this image any more in webpage of Image Template Details until the transaction is finish.

Comment: I think this operation only affect create vm in idc D, not A , right? But the fact is that idc A,B,C also can't create vm this time.

Comment: Question 2: what's the different between SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group:getT‌​ransaction()  and SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group:getChild(mask=('transaction'))?     Does it mean I need call this two api to  confirm this image is in transaction?

Comment: Question 3: which operation can occurs SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group:getT‌​ra‌​nsaction()  return a transaction instead of empty str?   In other words, how to trigger the parent into transactoin?

Comment: Well, regarding to your first question, I did some tests and I'm able to create a VM in Datacenter A, B, C (When the image has a transaction in progress to copy in other datacenter). Anyway this shouldn't affect to create VMs, Also if you wish to create a vm in a datacenter in which the image doesn't have a copy. The image will be copy in this datacenter (automatically), after you place an order.

Comment: I recommend to use this page to order a vm from an image, if you wish to order through Control Portal:

[https://control.softlayer.com/devices/images](https://control.softlayer.com/devices/images)

Because the **Actions** options is disabled in the image template page when it has a transaction in progress (it seems a bug, you can submit a ticket for further investigation about it, anyway, I will try to investigate more about it and I will let you know any news).

Comment: Regarding to your second and third question, you only should make a call to **SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group:getChild‌​(mask=mask[transaction]** to check for transaction (if you are trying to add/delete locations), because we only link the transaction on the child image template since we're using it to do the copy. 

The **SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group::getTransaction** will show a transaction in case that the image is being exported

Comment: Hi Ruber, I have known that we can use SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group:getChild‌​‌​(mask=mask[transac‌​tion]  to get the clone image template. Now I want to know which clone (in which data-center) is in transaction. I use getChild() function with the mask:MASK=('id,name,datacenters,transaction'), the result is `[{'datacenters': [], 'id': 1331707, 'name': 'lipp-test-system-disk-only'},{'datacenters': [],'id': 1333919, 'name': 'lipp-test-system-disk-only',
  'transaction': {...'transactionStatus': {... 'name': 'DELETE_CLOUD_DISK_TEMPLATE'}}}]`。

Comment: How can I get the children's transaction happening in which datacenter?

Comment: Or how can I know which clone image by the getChildren() result: {'datacenters': [], 'id': 1331707, 'name': 'lipp-test-system-disk-only'} . Is the  id:1331707 refer to the child's id. Can I get the location information by this id?

Comment: Oh, I have found the mask item datacenter and it works. I can get the child image location now.  Best regard~

Comment: Oh that's great! regards